# How do I implement no hold and wait to prevent a deadlock

Tags: c++, deadlock

I have written an intentionally deadlocked code which has 2 locks and the way I'm deadlocking the program is like this:

```
void ThreadAtWork1(){
  m1.lock();
  cout<<"Thread 1 has been called\n";
  m2.lock();
  m1.unlock();
  m2.unlock();
}

void ThreatAtWork2(){
  m2.lock();
  cout<<"Thread 2 has been called\n";
  m1.lock();
  m2.unlock();
  m1.unlock();

}
```

How can I implement a no 'hold and wait' solution to stop the program from deadlocking? I know I can just re-order the locks but that won't solve the no hold and wait solution.

My main function:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

thread t1(ThreadAtWork1);
thread t2(ThreatAtWork2);

t1.join();
t2.join();

cout<<"\nMain exited...\n";

return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: We need more context. You haven't said what synchronization-primitive library you're using, or your platform, etc.

Comment: What are `m1` and `m2`? Please provide a [MCVE] to better illustrate your problem.

Comment: Use a `std::timed_mutex` and release all locks if they timeout before trying again. Use an increasing delay to avoid problems.

Comment: The tag shows C++. I thought that was clear. m1 and m2 are mutex locks. I said that there were 2 locks in the problem description (maybe should've clarified it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did figure it out a while ago but forgot to update this post. Below is how I went about it and got 100 on it.

```
//for hold and wait, just don't allocate the resource if a thread asks for it. Just wait and execute the other one

//t1-> request W. requires W
//t2-> has W
//t1 checks if W is free. wait
//t2 executes. Releases W
//t1 executes

//basically, if all locks are free, execute, else not.
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the "no hold and wait" is a general principle where you try to avoid making blocking calls while having a mutex locked. Doing that may easily cause a deadlock unless you are very careful.

If you do have to have two mutexes locked at the same time, "no hold and wait" is not an option for you.

Often you can re-design your system not to require having two mutexes locked at the same time. For instance, it's totally OK to have more than one condition variable associated with the same mutex.

Comment: It doesn't have to use mutex locks to implement the "no hold and wait". How should I go about it?

Comment: @ElDj In your example you could go with just one mutex or even without any mutexes. There is no general recipe here, it very much depends on the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: How will one mutex implement no hold and wait?

Comment: @ElDj If you use only one mutex in your example, you won't be doing any blocking calls while holding it. Again, "no hold and wait" is not a specific technique but rather a general idea that blocking calls while holding a mutex should be avoided if possible.

Comment: So should I use one mutex at a time in my `main()` function where I call `ThreadAtWork1()` and the second one?

Comment: @ElDj You haven't showed us your `main()` function. It's not clear why should it touch those mutexes.

Comment: i added my main, can you please check it?

Comment: @ElDj There is no reason to use two mutexes in your example. One would be sufficient. In fact, since `std::cout` is internally synchronized, you don't strictly need even one mutex.